# Read/write variable from/to tree

Tags: haskell, tree, nodes

I defined a tree:

```
data PersonNode = PersonNode 
    { age :: Int 
     , name :: String } 
deriving (Ord,Eq,Show,Read)

type PersonTree = Tree PersonNode
```

My questions are how do i get the name from my node and use it somewhere else. A better example would be if i have an Int Tree and i would add the values from the tree and add it to my tree as seen above:

So the function would be:

```
import Data.Tree
f: [a] -> [Tree Int] -> [PersonTree]
```

It takes the Ints from the Data.Tree and should add it to the PersonNode as an age and takes the information from the list and puts it into the name in this case. 
My Problem is that i dont know how to get the information from the Data.Tree and put it into the PersonTree as the specific variable.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: What's the `[a]` argument here?  Should it instead be `[String]` to represent names?  Is a list for names and a tree for ages the best way to go about this?

Comment: Yeah in this case it should be a [String]. A List for names and a tree for ages might be not be optimal but its just for my example where i want to read inforamtion from one tree and but it into another one. Essetially transforming a tree into another tree.

Comment: The tree transform is pretty easy, but what order do you want to assign names from the list to ages in the tree?  You could do depth-first or breadth-first, or something else entirely.

Comment: The list is random so it doesnt matter that much. Its just so i can understand the process and how to do something like this. If it would matter I like to use depth-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a simple example, if we had something like

```
names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
ageTree =
    Node 1 [
        Node 2 [
            Node 3 []
            ],
        Node 4 [
            Node 5 [],
            Node 6 []
            ],
        Node 7 []
        ]
```

Then we want that `buildPersonTree names ageTree` to output something like

```
Node (Person 1 "A") [
    Node (Person 2 "B") [
        Node (Person 3 "C") []
        ],
    Node (Person 4 "D") [
        Node (Person 5 "E") [],
        Node (Person 6 "F") []
        ],
    Node (Person 7 "G") []
    ]
```

This can be accomplish several ways, direct recursion would being one of those, but that can get tricky because you need to fully traverse one branch before you go down the next while keeping up with what names were assigned on the first branch.  Instead, we can use the state monad to make this almost trivial, if somewhat less efficient:

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State


data PersonNode = PersonNode { age :: Int, name :: String } deriving (Eq, Show)


mkPerson :: (Functor m, MonadState [String] m) => Int -> m (Maybe PersonNode)
mkPerson age' = do
    -- name' :: Maybe String
    name' <- listToMaybe <$> get
    -- Remove that name from the head of the list of names
    modify (drop 1)
    -- fmap PersonNode over our Maybe String in name'
    return $ PersonNode age' <$> name'

buildTree :: (Functor m, MonadState [String] m) => Tree Int -> m (Maybe (Tree PersonNode))
buildTree (Node age' children) = do
    -- Get the root PersonNode using mkPerson
    root <- mkPerson age'
    -- children' :: [Maybe (Tree PersonNode)]
    children' <- mapM buildTree children
    -- Applicative combinators make error handling simple
    return $ Node <$> root <*> sequence children'

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn
     $ maybe "Not enough names" (drawTree . fmap show)
     $ evalState (buildTree testAgeTree) testNames

testAgeTree :: Tree Int
testAgeTree = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 []], Node 4 [Node 5 [], Node 6 []], Node 7 []]

testNames :: [String]
testNames = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
```

I made sure to use `Maybe` to indicate failure to get a name from the list, so that makes things a bit more complicated, but other than that Haskell allows us to use very simple recursion to build up the child nodes, and the monad combinators `mapM` and `sequence` make this very simple.  The applicative combinators also make the error handling virtually transparent, I never had to mention `Just` or `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching combined with recursion does this!

```
addAge :: Tree Int -> Tree PersonNode -> Tree PersonNode
addAge (Node addTreeRoot []) (Node personsRoot []) = (Node (PersonNode { age = addTreeRoot + (age personsRoot), name = (name personsRoot) }) [])
addAge (Node addTreeRoot addTreeForest) (Node personsRoot personsForest) = Node (PersonNode { age = addTreeRoot + (age personsRoot), name = (name personsRoot) } (addAge addTreeForest personsForest)
```

Notes: it fails on trees that are not the same size. If this is a problem, you'll need to adapt this and I didn't test it. I hope it gets the idea across though.

**Edit:** seems I completely misunderstood the question. I think, though, that the above example is helpful by demonstrating how to deconstruct a tree.

Comment: Thanks that helped.So for the standard Data.Tree I have to use age = (rootlabel Node)?

Comment: No, since `Node` is not defined using record syntax that won't work (unless you define `rootlabel (Node lbl _) = lbl`). You should get at the rootlabel using [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). @user3657850